# Value removed from HashMap during iteration

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

I have a HashMap with the addresses and the names of the clients that are assigned on a server.When a user signs off everybody receives a message about his departure and then I
remove him from the HashMap.
The problem is when I iterate the HashMap in order to send to everyone the message I use
a thread and as a result the users is removed before iteration happens, thus he don't receives the message.
I tried Hashtable , ConcurrentHashMap in vain.
When i skip the line of removal then it works.
How can I avoid it ,can I use a different kind of map;

```
private HashMap<InetAddress, String> users = new HashMap<InetAddress, String>();
```

.
.
.

```
 UDPServerSender sender = new UDPServerSender(str, address, true);
                        sender.start();
                        users.remove(address);
```

.
.
.

```
public class UDPServerSender extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            iterator = users.keySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                InetAddress inetaddress = (InetAddress) iterator.next();
```

I figured I can send a separate message to the signed off users.

Comment: The simple answer is that to guarantee that the user is or isn't in the table when you are iterating, you need to do these two operations in 1 thread ie in sequence

Comment: You should synchronize the threads via an appropriate measure and ensure the execture order sending->deletion.

Comment: Since you call `start()` before `remove()`, there's absolutely no guarantee as to what will happen in what order.

Comment: Could anyone give me an example of synchronization?What should I do?Encapsulate the HashMap and synchronize the getter/setter?

Comment: @giannosfor The issue is not with synchronizing access to your `HashMap` but rather synchronizing the execution order of operations between your threads. If you can't do that or do not want to you can instead create a copy of your `HashMap` and run the message broadcast on that copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the thread should be removing the address, not the main thread. To do so, you will need to pass the `HashMap` to the thread.

Another alternative is to wait for the thread to finish before removing the address. Just use `join` to  wait until the thread is done:

```
 UDPServerSender sender = new UDPServerSender(str, address, true);
                        sender.start();
                        sender.join();
                        users.remove(address);
```

Be aware that this second approach defeats the purpose of having a separate thread though, since it kills all parallelism (messages are now sent one by one).